# VBA code to stack multiple columns in range into one column gets Run Time Error 1004 (Paste and copy area not same size and shape)

Tags: excel, vba

Error Location in Code: Rng2.Offset (RowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True.

I have the text of a book currently stored in multiple columns. The range of all cells containing text is labelled "MyData". What I'm trying to do is stack all the columns into one single column of data, but right now, it only seems to be copying over one column of data to the second sheet, when prompted. I've uploaded my raw data to my [Google Drive][1], too, if anybody wants to see what I'm working with.

```
Sub StackDataToOneColumn()


Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng As Range

Dim RowIndex As Long

Set Rng1 = Application.Selection

Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select Range:", "StackDataToOneColumn", Rng1.Address, Type:=8)

Set Rng2 = Application.InputBox("Destination Column:", "StackDataToOneColumn", Type:=8)

RowIndex = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



For Each Rng In Rng1.Rows

    Rng.Copy

    Rng2.Offset(RowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

    RowIndex = RowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CN7KftcnLxr5WOrqx-qie4r2RplnKnil/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Please, better explain (**in words**) what you try doing. Don't you want writing rows which are split on many columns **in single cells** on the second workbook?

Comment: In single cells of A:A column, I meant...

Comment: Either explain in details with example of what you want to do or show a "before" and "after" screenshot of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next code and send some feedback:

```
Sub PutEachWordOnOneCellInAA()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, arr1
   Dim rngCells As Range, arrRow, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1 (2)")
   lastR = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Set rngCells = sh1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'only cells not being empty
   ReDim arrFin(1 To rngCells.Count, 1 To 1): k = 1

   arr1 = sh1.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2                                'to iterate faster
   
   For i = 1 To lastR
        lastCol = sh1.Cells(i, sh1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arrRow = sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(i, "A"), sh1.Cells(i, lastCol)).Value2
        If IsArray(arrRow) Then 'if more then one column:
            For j = 1 To lastCol
              arrFin(k, 1) = arrRow(1, j): k = k + 1
            Next j
        Else                             'if only one word per A:A cell
            arrFin(k, 1) = arrRow: k = k + 1
        End If
   Next i
   sh2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: @Madhuri Vairapandi You can download your processed workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/mmrhpm). I hope I correctly understood what you need. You did not answer any clarification question...

Comment: @Madhuri Vairapandi Didn't you find some time to test the above code, or the workbook I sent? If tested, didn't the code do what you need?

Comment: Hey, sorry - I've been working all day and just am getting back on! Thanks for poking around, and I wish I'd gotten my clarifying answers to you before you went ahead and put the paragraphs back together (funnily enough, that's the format of the data that I'd initially gotten before I separated out the individual words).

I want to be able to analyze every single word used within this book. So, I was going to put each individual word into a column and then I can sort, analyze, and organize the language manually. I just need them all in one column so I can play with the data.

Comment: @Madhuri Vairapandi I am afraid, I cannot get you... Did the above code what you need or not? Did you see the workbook I sent? Isn't it what you need?

Comment: The code you provided in the workbook wasn't what I wanted. There are nearly 166k individual words across all columns. I want them all in one column.

Comment: @Madhuri Vairapandi I did not understand too much from your question. I asked clarification questions, I made suppositions and I did what I understood. Now, do you want placing **all words in column A:A, one word per cell**? The above code, places all existing rows (many cells, or only one) in one cell of A:A column.

Comment: @Madhuri Vairapandi Please, check the updated code. Now, it puts each word in one cel of column A:A. Please, download the processed workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/ca8eel) and send some feedback.